# Fire event at Infinite horizontal scroll end in ionic 5

Tags: css, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll, horizontal-scrolling, ionic5

I am trying to build infinite scrolling content horizontally. Following code does the job on the first load.

HTML:

```
  <div class="thumnails">
    <div class="list-thumbnail">
      <div class="img-thumb" *ngFor="let user of userList">
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            {{user.name}}
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.thumnails{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    .list-thumbnail{
      height: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      .img-thumb{
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 3px;
      }
    }
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
  }
```

After this, I need to fire a method when a user reaches the end on scroll. Ionic has the component `ion-infinite-scroll` which works in vertical scroll but it's not firing when I use it with the above code.

Is there a way to fire an event at the end of the horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying the ionScroll event from ion-content component.

1. Enable ionScroll like:

   <ion-content [scrollEvents]="true" (ionScroll)="logScrolling($event)">
2. On logScrolling check to see if the scroll reached a certain point. If it did, add more data to your infinite scrolling content:

   ```
   async logScrolling($event) {
      if($event.target.localName != "ion-content") {
         return;
       }
      const scrollElement = await $event.target.getScrollElement();
      const scrollWidth = scrollElement.scrollWidth - scrollElement.clientWidth;
      const threshold = 50;
      if(scrollWidth < threshold) {
         //...load data here
      }}
   ```

I did not test it but it should work like that. Please let me know if you ran into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Is not beautiful and I did not test it for performance issues but it does exactly what you want

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="thumnails" (scroll)="scrollEv($event)">
    <div class="list-thumbnail">
      <div class="img-thumb" *ngFor="let user of userList">
        <span class="id" hidden>{{ user.id }}</span>
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            {{ user.name }}
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

TS:

```
  userList: Array<any> = [];
  // elements count till the end of list to trigger the `getData()` function
  elementsToTrigger: number = 10;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  scrollEv(ev) {
    // get the last visible on screen element of the list by it's coordenates:
    // x => the offsetWidth of the body - 5px so it doesn't get out of boundaries
    // y => distance the list is from the top. Note that here the list is fixed at the top because it's the only element on screen, but if, at some point,
    // it will scroll or be placed at someplace else you should get this distance manually before this next line.
    let elByCoords = document.elementFromPoint(document.body.offsetWidth - 5, 0);
    let elId = elByCoords.children[0].textContent;

    // check if the last element visible on screen is the "elementsToTrigger'th to last" and if so get more data
    // here you should also check if all data has been loaded so you don't keep sending requests to your backend
    if ((this.userList.length - this.userList.findIndex(user => user.id === +elId)) <= this.elementsToTrigger) {
      this.getData();
    }
  }

  getData() {
    // here goes your logic to retrieve more results from database.
    let startAt: number = this.userList?.length || 0;
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = startAt; i < startAt + 50; i++) {
      arr.push({ id: i, name: `User ${i}` });
    }
    this.userList = (this.userList || []).concat(arr);
  }
```

You may need to play a little with `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` to find the correct values